How rith belongsToMany relation get number of related rows?
In laravel 11 app User model have defined relation :
    namespace App\Models;
    
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
    ...
    class User extends Authenticatable
    {
    
        public function uncompletedTasks(): belongsToMany
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany(Task::class)
                ->using(TaskUser::class)
                ->withPivot('supervisor_id')   // Reference to "task_user" table
                ->where('completed', false)
                ->orderBy('priority', 'desc')
                ->orderBy('deadline_at', 'desc');
        }

and when I need to get number of related data I do :
$this->uncompletedTasksCount = count($this->loggedUser->uncompletedTasks);

I check sql-tracement like:

    SELECT `tasks`.*, `task_user`.`user_id`     AS `pivot_user_id`, `task_user`.`task_id`     AS `pivot_task_id`, `task_user`.`supervisor_id`     AS `pivot_supervisor_id`
    FROM `tasks`
    INNER JOIN `task_user` on `tasks`.`id` = `task_user`.`task_id`
    WHERE `task_user`.`user_id` = 1     AND `completed` = ''
    ORDER BY `priority` desc, `deadline_at` desc

Question is how can I change my request to get count in sql request(not reading collection of data and php "count" method) to reduce trafik ?

As far as I understand your question, you can do it
 Using withCount method  
$userWithTaskCount = auth()->user()->withCount(['uncompletedTasks']);
This will add an attribute named uncompleted_tasks_count to your user model, which you can access later.
 OR 
Modifying just modify your Relationship Query  
If you want to include the count directly in the relationship query, you can modify your uncompletedTasks method. However,
you don’t need to add
 selectRaw('count(*) as uncompleted_tasks_count')
directly in the relationship method, or simply you use count() on the relationship when needed this is also better approach $count = auth()->user()->uncompletedTasks()->count();
which will return the count of uncompleted tasks without loading the entire collection of tasks.

Pls simply do this:
 $this->uncompletedTasksCount = $this->loggedUser->uncompletedTasks()->count();

For more information pls check out the sections of querying relations and aggregations in the docs.

Thank you! It works ok. Could you please explain the difference in $this->loggedUser->uncompletedTasks and $this->loggedUser->uncompletedTasks()->count() ?
